# How can I add some random jitter to the timing of notes in SuperCollider Patterns?

Tags: scheduling, design-patterns, timing, supercollider

I'd like to add a very simple "humanisation" to some note patterns, by randomly jittering the time that the notes play. This code repeatedly plays a chord:

```
p = Pbind(\legato, 0.1, \dur, 0.2, \midinote, [66, 69, 74]).play
```

But I'd like each of the three notes in the chord to randomly have some independent "error" in the exact timing. I do **not** want the tempo to vary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a key you can use called \timingOffset - described in [section 8 of the pattern guide](http://doc.sccode.org/Tutorials/A-Practical-Guide/PG_08_Event_Types_and_Parameters.html).

The simple example is:

```
p = Pbind(\legato, 0.1, \dur, 0.4, \midinote, [66, 69, 74], 
       \timingOffset, Pwhite(-0.1, 0.1)
    ).play;
```

so that's a random offset of +-0.1 beats. Unfortunately it applies one deviation to the whole chord, which is not what you want. So you need to feed an array into the Pwhite:

```
p = Pbind(\legato, 0.1, \dur, 0.4, \midinote, [66, 69, 74], 
       \timingOffset, Pwhite([-0.1, -0.1, -0.1], [0.1, 0.1, 0.1])
    ).play;
```

and of course you can derive those arrays from some value:

```
~jitter = 0.1;
p = Pbind(\legato, 0.1, \dur, 0.4, \midinote, [66, 69, 74], 
       \timingOffset, Pwhite({0-~jitter}.dup(3), {~jitter}.dup(3))
    ).play;
```

Here's a slightly different approach which makes the right number of values, in case the array size of "midinote" is variable:

```
~jitter = 0.1;
p = Pbind(\legato, 0.1, \dur, 0.4, \midinote, [66, 69, 74], 
\timingOffset, Pcollect({|val| {~jitter.bilinrand}.dup(val.size)}, Pkey(\midinote))
    ).play;
```

Comment: OK this works - **but** can the number of Pwhite items be derived automatically, if the number of the notes in the chord is variable?

Comment: Added one way of doing that, above